# React Native Push Notification on debug works, on release it's not - Android

Tags: android, react-native-push-notification

I see there is an open [issue](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1005) for `react-native-push-notification`. Just wondering if anyone faced this issue.

I have tested my react native app when developing for android 8 and android 9. Push notification does show up. But when I build apk from the same code, everything works other than the push notification.

As a note, I use `npx jetify` manually for androidX conversion.